# Spring boot application with Spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-test makes spring does not find application properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-starter

I have created a small application with spring boot that access to a database (mySql) using spring data:

> - spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.4.2
> - spring-boot-starter-web: 2.4.2
> - spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 2.4.2
> - mysql-connector-java: 8.0.22
> - spring-boot-starter-test: 2.4.2
> - org.junit.jupiter: 5.7.0
> - junit-jupiter-engine: 5.7.0

I have configured my application.properties, inside src/main/resources, and I have configured the properties for url, username, password, driver, ..., like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BBDD
spring.datasource.username=XXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXX
spring.datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

I have an interface for my repository for access to my database:

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ArticuloEntity, Integer> {

}
```

also, I have defined my entity.

The issue consists on when I start my webapp, I get an error because it does not read the parameters for configuring the datasource from the application.properties:

> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
> Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
> to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
> profiles are currently active).

If I remove the dependencies for spring-boot-starter-test and junit, the application loads fine, and it access to database. But if I add the dependency for adding my junits, it does not read my application.properties file and I get the previous error.

How can I have my application configured with junits and reading the configuration for my application with the application.properties file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your test/application.properties needs to be configured as well. Try adding this to your test application properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:BBDD;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

and this to your pom if you don't already support h2.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your application.properties

changing

```
spring.datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```